# Is there a type of pump or device that will sit on a flooded floor and quietly suck up a puddle of water?

Tags: pump, flooding

There is a slow leak in our finished basement - it should be fixed eventually but we are looking for an interim solution to a constant puddle of water in the middle of the floor.

- Floor is ceramic tile
- Puddle is near or sometimes in an en suite full bathroom, so with some sort of pump the water could be diverted into a bathtub about 4' away
- The room is being used as an office, so the solution cannot be super loud
- The person using the office has mobility issues, so I am looking for something that can just sit in the puddle and work, as she would not be able to operate e.g. a shop-vac, and we have no way to clean or try towels or anything else used to sop up the water

Does such an appliance exist and what would it be called?

Comment: drill a hole or two in the bottom of an air conditioner condensate pump's tank to make a cheap automatic mini sump pump; ones been keeping my basement dry for 18 months or so now. A "real" sump pump will likely need a deeper puddle, whereas this setup can pull up an inch deep puddle, triggered by its float switch...

Comment: Where is the water coming from?

Answer (score 2):

[**Here is a sump pump**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07F9TDRT9) that is quiet, has automatic on/off with the presence of water down to 1/4" and has thermal protection for less than $100. You have the option of purchasing a discharge kit that will work up to 24' and a little check valve as well. All items together are just over $110.

[image]

Comment: Updated to a better model.